# Simple translate animation, not working on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, imageview, android-4.4-kitkat, android-framelayout, translate-animation

This is simple example of programmatically "**WITHOUT XML**" translate animation, that works perfect on all versión bellow Android 4.4.2., ***but does nothing on Android 4.4.2.*** It's really making me crazy!

Any ideas why?

## Edited- Tested on:

**Works on:**

EMULATOR, AVD with 4.1.2 (API 16), EMULATOR, AVD with 4.2.2 (API 17), EMULATOR, AVD with 4.3.1 (API 18), Galaxy Tab 3 (4.1.2), Surprice, surprice.....works on my Galaxy NOTE with Omnirom 4.4.4

**Not Working on:**

EMULATOR, AVD with 4.4.2 (API 19),  Galaxy S4 (4.4.2), Galaxy Note 3 (4.4.2)

```
public class ActivityTypeSF extends Activity{
Graphics graphics;
FrameLayout fl;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    int myWidth = 1280;
    int myHeight = 800;
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    int frameBufferWidth = isPortrait ? myHeight : myWidth;
    int frameBufferHeight = isPortrait ? myWidth : myHeight;

    Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth, frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);
    graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);

    fl = new FrameLayout(this);
    ImageView mons= new ImageView(this);
    mons.setImageBitmap(graphics.newImage("mons/mons01.png", ImageFormat.ARGB8888).getBitmap());
    mons.setX(400);
    mons.setY(200);

    TranslateAnimation aniTrans = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -200);
    aniTrans.setDuration(5000);
    mons.setAnimation(aniTrans);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    fl.addView(mons, params);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams flp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    this.setContentView(fl, flp);

    mons.startAnimation(aniTrans);
    aniTrans.startNow();

}
```

---

(1.)
**Have found the problem**, but I need some help to solve it!
(NOTE: This only occurs in full java code. It doesn’t happened using XML file, what is not the case)

Take a look to this new example code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    common = new Common(this, this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams framelayoutparameter = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,           FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    /* I think that this is the line code (imageviewparamenter) were Android 4.4.2 FAILS during animation.
     */
    LayoutParams imageviewparamenter = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    /* 
     * No matter the size of the screen, Android 4.4.2 creates a black hole outside the image size,
     * just during animation (see attached picture). Thats why animation dont show up, if the 
     * initial position (setX or setY) of the image, is outside the image boundary.
     */

    fl = new FrameLayout(this);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

    /*  Image is located in the ASSET and is 100x100 pixels (non dpi dependable)
     *  "common" method use AssetManager to read the image file
     */
    iv.setImageBitmap(common.newImage("iv_image.png", ImageFormat.RGB565).getBitmap());
    iv.setX(50); // position show in the example 
    iv.setY(0);

    fl.addView(iv, imageviewparamenter);
    this.setContentView(fl, framelayoutparameter);

    AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0,1);
    animation.setDuration(5000);
    animation.setAnimationListener(this);

    /* Also, "setAnimation(animation)" must be present, in order that
     * Android 4.4.2 animates without skipping frames
     */
    iv.setAnimation(animation);

    iv.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Create a frame layout with a ImageView and alpha animation using pure java code. During animation, **Android 4.4.2 (API19)** is creating a black mask outside the ImageView size boundary, starting at x/y coordinates **(0 + imageWidth / 0 + imageHeight)**, so if you initially place the image outside that coordinate, you don’t see any animation, just the original image at the end of the animation....

To recreate the issue, i have place the image in **x = 50** . You would see that the half right side of the image is BLACK **during Android 4.4.2** animation. You can recreate using emulator with any size of screen setup that you prefer. Using API 16,17,18 have no problem, but using API19, the black mask will make you crazy!

NOW, ANY IDEAS? or is a big bug on Android 4.4.2? or I just don’t see it?

(2.) Also have found that if you don’t use setAnimation on android 4.4.2, the animation randomly fails and the Choreographer skips frames

NOTE: I will post the images that illustrate the issue, as soon i earn more reputation. Thanks!

EDITED: I need to upload the pictures that explain this issue, but since SO its not so friendly to new users, just follow this link to see the images:

**http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=56553476&postcount=2**

Comment: I have noticed that the problem is for any type of animation of the “android.view.animation” API (translate, alpha, rotation, scale.). Sometimes, it responds to the animation, but without showing the transition, it shows the final of the animation. Other times, it jumps many stages of the animation and other times it is not executed. In the above example code, the object just shows at the end of the animation (does not move). If I change the animation to AlphaAnimation (fadeIn), simply shows the end.

Comment: Aditional note: In Android 4.4.2, the "Choreographer" is Skippin all the frames in the example above!. That does not happening with version's bellow 4.4.2. Any ideas why?